# BootstrapVue VeeValidate - show an extra error message when form is invalid

Tags: validation, vue.js, vue-component, bootstrap-vue, vee-validate

I am using [BootstrapVue](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/) and [VeeValidate](https://logaretm.github.io/vee-validate/guide/forms.html#validate-before-submit) in my Laravel + Vue.js SPA (Single Page Appplication). When form fields are invalid, it automatically shows errors in respective positions. But I need a way so that whenever any form input is invalid I can show a message ( i.e. 'Invalid data') within a `div` with `id`  `result` just above the `form`.

My `Register.vue` component has the following form :

```
<template>

    <ValidationObserver ref="form" v-slot="{ passes }">

        <div id="registration_form">
            <div id="page_header" class="text-center" >Register</div>
        <div id="result" v-html="result" class="result text-center"></div>

        <b-form @submit.prevent="passes(onSubmit)" @reset="resetForm">



            <ValidationProvider vid="name" rules="required|min:2" name="name" v-slot="{ valid, errors }">
                <b-form-group
                        label="User Name:"
                        label-for="exampleInput1"

                >
                    <b-form-input
                            type="text"
                            disable-leading-trailing-space
                            v-model="name"
                            :state="errors[0] ? false : (valid ? true : null)"
                            placeholder="Enter your name"
                    ></b-form-input>
                    <b-form-invalid-feedback id="inputLiveFeedback">{{ errors[0] }}</b-form-invalid-feedback>
                </b-form-group>
            </ValidationProvider>


            <ValidationProvider vid="email" rules="required|email" name="Email" v-slot="{ valid, errors }">
                <b-form-group
                        label="Email address:"
                        label-for="exampleInput1"
                        description="We'll never share your email with anyone else."
                >
                    <b-form-input
                            type="email"
                            disable-leading-trailing-space
                            v-model="email"
                            :state="errors[0] ? false : (valid ? true : null)"
                            placeholder="Enter email"
                    ></b-form-input>
                    <b-form-invalid-feedback id="inputLiveFeedback">{{ errors[0] }}</b-form-invalid-feedback>
                </b-form-group>
            </ValidationProvider>

        <b-button type="submit" variant="primary">Submit</b-button>
            <b-button type="reset" variant="danger">Reset</b-button>
        </b-form>

        </div><!-- end of id registration_form-->
    </ValidationObserver>
</template>
```

JS part has :

```
<script>
    import { ValidationObserver, ValidationProvider } from "vee-validate";

    export default {
        name: "Register",
        components: {
            ValidationObserver,
            ValidationProvider
        },
        data: () => ({
            name: "",
            email: "",
            result:''
        }),
        methods: {
            onSubmit() {
                console.log("Form submitted yay!");
            },
            resetForm() {
                this.name = "";
                this.email = "";

                requestAnimationFrame(() => {
                    this.$refs.form.reset();
                });
            }
        }
    }; 
</script>
```

Whenever any `form` input is in invalid condition, I want to show in `div` with `id` `result` the message 'Invalid data'.

Is there any event like `beforeSubmit` or any other way to accomplish that ?

**EDIT:**
         I also want to scroll the window to the top (`window.scrollTo(0,0)`) whenever any validation error occurs in front end. How to do that ?

Comment: on veevalidate website there is a validation before submit. is that what you mean ?

Comment: what is the link ?

Comment: check it here https://logaretm.github.io/vee-validate/guide/forms.html#basic-example its on top of the page

Comment: can you paste the code here ?

Comment: you can check it here for the example, https://codesandbox.io/s/jdqzk

Comment: 'validation before submit' - where did you use it ?

Comment: @pinoyCoder, from the link you gave : ' the handleSubmit function accepts a submit handler and will only execute the handler once the user submits a valid form.  '. So if the form is invalid, will the handler method work ? How can it solve my problem ?

Comment: you need to check the documentation i guess, that will you solve your problem all of the things you require is there, you just need to read it, please refer to the Validation before submit and the Rules.

Answer (score 0):

Grab the `failed` state from the `ValidationObserver` slot props:

```html
<ValidationObserver ref="form" v-slot="{ failed, passes }">
  <div v-if="failed">Invalid Data</div>

<!-- rest of your fields -->
</ValidationObserver>
```

Comment: Added 'EDIT:' in OP

Comment: where is the rule you said in the doc ?